# Entity Framework Filtering

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I want to apply filters on my query something like this

```
filters.Aggregate(query, (current, filter) => current.Where(filter));
```

But this creates query with AND as binder for example, if my filters are name="abc" , state="xyz"
Applying the above expression i get my query as

```
select * from SomeTable where name="abc" **AND** state="xyz"
```

But i want it work like

```
select * from SomeTable where name="abc" **OR** state="xyz" instead
```

how should I change it, Please help

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = from a in db.tablename
             where a.name=="abc" || a.state== "xyz"
             select a;
OR 

var result =  db.tablename.where(a=> (a.name.Equals("abc")) ||                           
              (a.state.Equals("xyz"));
```